# Opening Wallet with a different App

Tags: wallet, electrum

I just bought a couple of bitcoins. I got my wallet from Bitcom.org but I learned that there is this Electrum wallet which Id like to try. How do I open my wallet with the new App?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to switch to Electrum is to send all the bitcoins you have on your old wallet to one of the addresses on your Electrum wallet. This way you'll have all your bitcoins secured with your seed.

You could import the private keys from your old client, but you will have to keep a backup of those keys separately as they won't become part of your Electrum seed.

http://electrum.org/tutorials.html#switching-to-electrum